# Why does np.arange(10,1, 1) produce an empty array?

Tags: python, numpy

Why does `np.arange(10,1, 1)` produce an empty array, whereas `np.arange(10,1, -1)`, on the other hand, produces what one would expect (an array from 10 down)?

Comment: If you start from 10, and increment by one each time, how long until you reach 1? See, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Same reason `range(10, 1, 1)` and `xrange(10, 1, 1)` produce empty output.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect `np.arange(10,1,1)` to produce?  You start at 10, step by 1, and stop when the result is 1 (or more).  Same reasoning is used in Python `range`

> Values are generated within the half-open interval `[start, stop)`
>   (in other words, the interval including `start` but excluding `stop`).
>   For integer arguments the function is equivalent to the Python built-in
>   `range <http://docs.python.org/lib/built-in-funcs.html>`_ function,
>   but returns an ndarray rather than a list.

for `range`:

> If step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop;

```
>>> range(1, 0)
[]
```

Compare `x[::2]` with `x[::-2]` for some array or list to see the usefulness of paying attention to the sign of the `step`.